# PreparedStatement executeUpdate() updates wrong record

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am using an Oracle database and after sometime I receive the following Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
```

I analysed my code and I seem to be closing all the ResultSet. This Exception only happens sometimes. Due to this error, I decided to change my code a little bit. Below is the code:

```
public class Audit {

    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement insertAuditPreparedStatementSent;
    private static int counter;
    private static int JDBC_COUNTER;

    public Audit() throws Exception {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("url", "username", "password");
    }

public int insertAudit(String message, java.util.Date sent) throws Exception {
     PreparedStatment preparedStatement = prepareStatement(new String("INSERT INTO Audit (message, sent) VALUES (?, ?)");
     if(JDBC_COUNTER == 0) {
            // this is required to be executed so that ORA-08002 SQLException is not thrown
            connection.createStatement().executeQuery(new String("SELECT AUDIT_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL"));
        }
     ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(new String("SELECT AUDIT_SEQUENCE.CURRVAL FROM DUAL"));
     resultSet.next();
     primaryKey = resultSet.getInt(new String("CURRVAL"));
     resultSet.close();
     return primaryKey;
}

public void executeUpdateAudit(int id, java.util.Date sent) throws Exception {
    if(updateAuditPreparedStatement == null) {
         updateAuditPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(new String("UPDATE AUDIT SET SENT = ? WHERE AUDIT_ID = " + id));
    }
    updateAuditPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(sent.getDate());
    int i = updateAuditPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    connection.commit();   
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Audit audit = new Audit();
     int primaryKey = audit.insertAudit("message", new java.util.Date());
     audit.executeUpdateAudit(primaryKey, new java.util.Date());
     int primaryKey2 = audit.insertAudit("message2", new java.util.Date());
     audit.executeUpdateAudit(primaryKey2, new java.util.Date());  
}
}
```

When inserting record 2 and updating record 2 only the `updateAuditPreparedStatement.executeUpdate()` returns 1, but the database updates the first record rather than the second record.

The reason to change the code is because I believe the PreparedStatement creates a new cursor each time. So, I want the insertAuditPreparedStatementSent to be there on many inserts without closing. I have tried `insertAuditPreparedStatementSent.clearBatch()` and `insertAuditPreparedStatementSent.clearParameters()`.

I am not sure why it is updating record 1 on the primaryKey of record 2. The SQL is fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing this:

```
if(JDBC_COUNTER == 0) {
    // this is required to be executed so that ORA-08002 SQLException is not thrown
    connection.createStatement().executeQuery(new String("SELECT AUDIT_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL"));
}
```

Also prepared statements needs to be closed as well and you are missing `try/catch/finally` in all these methods to prevent resource leakage. I strongly discourage using JDBC directly as it is very hard to work with.

Comment: I am closing my resultSet. Have a look in the method insertAudit() method. I have to use JDBC as my company will not allow anything other than JDBC. I want to stop the java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded Exception. So, I decided not to close the PreparedStatement and re-use it for all inserts. Is this a problem? Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: With Java 7 try-with-resources it got a lot easier to handle JDBC resources correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In `executeUpdateAudit` you prepare the statement once using the first ID seen:

```
if(updateAuditPreparedStatement == null) {
     updateAuditPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
         new String("UPDATE AUDIT SET SENT = ? WHERE AUDIT_ID = " + id));
}
updateAuditPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(1,
  new java.sql.Timestamp(sent.getDate());
```

In the second call the ID from the first call is still being used, since it's effectively hard-coded in the SQL.

You should be using a parameter for the ID as well:

```
if(updateAuditPreparedStatement == null) {
     updateAuditPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
         new String("UPDATE AUDIT SET SENT = ? WHERE AUDIT_ID = ?"));
}
updateAuditPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(1,
    new java.sql.Timestamp(sent.getDate());
updateAuditPreparedStatement.setInt(2, id);
```

Not sure why you're using `new String` explicitly everywhere; it would be a little simpler as:

```
if(updateAuditPreparedStatement == null) {
     updateAuditPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
         "UPDATE AUDIT SET SENT = ? WHERE AUDIT_ID = ?");
}
updateAuditPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(1,
    new java.sql.Timestamp(sent.getDate());
updateAuditPreparedStatement.setInt(2, id);
```

This is nothing to do with your ORA-01000, but this seems to be the main thrust of this question - you shouldn't really ask about two things at once, particularly if they aren't directly related...

Answer (score -1):

Please check the oracle parameter

open_cursors

You will find this in the enterprise manager or by executing the following SQL:

```
select * from v$parameter a
where a.NAME = 'open_cursors';
```

If this parameter is very low (e.g. < 300) and you have lots of processes/users working at the same time, this error can happen.